# How To read/write C array stored in text file created through bin2C utility

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, programming-languages

I am creating a application, input to which is a C file having an array ( which is created with bin2C.exe ) , the code segment of the C file is:-

```
unsigned int MyArray[] = { 0x00000001,0x00000002,0x00000005 ...};
```

now I need to read this array as a text file and story its value in an int array. Then I need to modify that array and put it back to text file so that the final output would look like:-

```
unsigned int MyArray[] = { 0x39481212,0x33943121,0x3941212 ...};
```

Please let me know how can I do this in C/VisualC++  as my application is in VC++ with MFC?

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

> input

open the file (`fopen`) in text mode and read the lines (`fgets` and `sscanf`)

> store array

you cannot have an array with unspecified size. You must either use a size limit and leave some elements unused, or use `malloc` and friends and manage storage for the array manually

> modify

use `+`, `-`, `*` and other operators along with `sqrt`, `abs`, `sin` and other functions available in the Standard Library to massage the data (you can create some functions of your own too)

> put it back

It's better to write to a new file and if everything went ok, delete the old file and rename the new one ... so open the new file (`fopen` with "w" for mode parameter) at the beginning when opening the input; if the input is not the array line write (`fputs`) it back directly, otherwise write the 'massaged' line; read and write all the other lines.

> (C++?) with MFC

The above is for `C`. It might work for `C++` with or without MFC

> Regards

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks,but I really dont understand what it meant when you say use library functions?

Comment: The Standard Library defines many functions declared in a few headers documented by your compiler documentation. For example, `abs` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`; `sqrt` and many other useful functions are declared in `<math.h>` ( http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/math.h.html )

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way was to read and use fprintf/sprintf functions to get and put the data as int from file.